# Spark 1.3.0 build failure

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

So, I am trying to build Spark 1.3.0 (standalone mode) on Windows 7 using Maven, but I'm getting a build failure. I am not sure if it is a dependency issue, or if something is wrong with Scala, or the plugin used to compile the project, or something else entirely.

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
```

Here is the command I am using to build:

```
mvn -DskipTests -X clean package
```

I get the following output:

```
[DEBUG] processing sourceDirectory=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\spark-1.3.0\mllib\src\main\scala encoding=null
error file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\spark-1.3.0\mllib\src\main\scala\org\apache\spark\mllib\clustering\LDAModel.scala message=Input length = 1
Saving to outputFile=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\spark-1.3.0\mllib\scalastyle-output.xml
Processed 143 file(s)
Found 1 errors
Found 0 warnings
Found 0 infos
Finished in 1032 ms
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Spark Project Parent POM ........................... SUCCESS [  5.456 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Networking ........................... SUCCESS [ 16.592 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Shuffle Streaming Service ............ SUCCESS [  9.359 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Core ................................. SUCCESS [03:48 min]
[INFO] Spark Project Bagel ................................ SUCCESS [ 20.622 s]
[INFO] Spark Project GraphX ............................... SUCCESS [ 49.076 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Streaming ............................ SUCCESS [01:22 min]
[INFO] Spark Project Catalyst ............................. SUCCESS [01:26 min]
[INFO] Spark Project SQL .................................. SUCCESS [01:47 min]
[INFO] Spark Project ML Library ........................... FAILURE [01:55 min]
[INFO] Spark Project Tools ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Hive ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project REPL ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Assembly ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External Twitter ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External Flume Sink .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External Flume ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External MQTT ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External ZeroMQ ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External Kafka ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Examples ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External Kafka Assembly .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12:01 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-03-30T15:06:01-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 67M/944M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.scalastyle:scalastyle-maven-plugin:0.4.0:check (default) on project spark-mllib_2.10: Failed during scalastyle execution: You have 1 Scalastyle violation(s). -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.scalastyle:scalastyle-maven-plugin:0.4.0:check (default) on project spark-mllib_2.10: Failed during scalastyle execution
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed during scalastyle execution
        at org.scalastyle.maven.plugin.ScalastyleViolationCheckMojo.performCheck(ScalastyleViolationCheckMojo.java:238)
        at org.scalastyle.maven.plugin.ScalastyleViolationCheckMojo.execute(ScalastyleViolationCheckMojo.java:199)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: You have 1 Scalastyle violation(s).
        at org.scalastyle.maven.plugin.ScalastyleViolationCheckMojo.performCheck(ScalastyleViolationCheckMojo.java:230)
        ... 22 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :spark-mllib_2.10
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0
```

How do I fix this?

UPDATE: Issue has been reported and resolved: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6532

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone else looking for a work-around for this issue, simply modify the following plugin in the pom.xml to include inputEncoding for UTF-8:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.scalastyle</groupId>
    <artifactId>scalastyle-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <verbose>false</verbose>
      <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
      <includeTestSourceDirectory>false</includeTestSourceDirectory>
      <failOnWarning>false</failOnWarning>
      <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
      <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
      <configLocation>scalastyle-config.xml</configLocation>
      <outputFile>scalastyle-output.xml</outputFile>
      <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
      <inputEncoding>UTF-8</inputEncoding> <!--add this line-->
    </configuration>
```

This only seems to be a problem for Windows users.

Comment: This is extremely helpful.  I see it's been patched in the latest (unpublished) version on github.