# Best way to Run Spark

Tags: apache-spark

There is a group project we are working on and we want to utilize spark.  However, we do not know what is the best way to run it on our computers.  We had thought maybe Hortonworks, and someone suggested looking at Maven.  We aren't sure though.

We are students so we can't buy anything (at least anything expensive).

When I search for ways to run Spark on my computer (windows), it usually pops up with compiling techniques or code help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have lots of options:

1. Download the [source from github](https://github.com/apache/spark) or [Apache](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html.) and run locally.
   The readme has instructions or you can download [Learning Spark](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028512.do)
   and read Chapter 2.
2. Download the [Cloudera Distribution Hadoop 5 QuickStart Virtual Machine](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cloudera_quickstart_vm.html). This requires a virtual machine player like VMWare or
   VirtualBox (Make sure VT-x is enabled in your BIOS). This runs Spark
   in a pseudo-distributed stand-alone mode and allows you to run it
   inside a Yarn container with some configuration changes. You also
   can run Spark locally out-of-the-box with all dependencies
   installed.
3. Download the Hortonworks virtual machine. It works very similar to Cloudera's offering but I am not as familiar with it.

I recommend Cloudera if your machine is capable of running a heavy-weight VM and you want to try running it in a pseudo-distributed environment. If you just want to learn how to program using the API, try the first option.

Comment: Thank you!  Great and thorough help!

Comment: @Mayuri Can you accept my answer if it answers all of your questions?

Comment: These are the most complicated options. What's wrong with downloading Spark and running it?

Comment: @DanielDarabos I just re-read my first point, and you're right - I missed the download packages. I'm updating my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and fastest way to run spark is to deploy it in standalone mode. See this guide: http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/spark-standalone.html

As you are working with Windows machines, I recommend taking a look at this before building with Maven: [Spark 1.3.0 build failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354461/spark-1-3-0-build-failure/29424704#29424704)

Once you've downloaded the source and modified the pom.xml, build using

```
mvn -DskipTests clean package
```

We might be able to give you a better answer if you tell us more about how you plan to be using spark for your project.

Answer (score -1):

1. Download a pre-built Spark version from http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html.
2. Run `bin/spark-shell.cmd`. See
   http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html.